# Does a Mesmerists Meek Facade trick prevent Attacks of Opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

The Mesmerist trick Meek Facade reads as follows:

> Meek Facade: The subject magically seems like a weak target, goading an enemy into attacking her. The mesmerist can trigger this trick when the subject misses a creature with an attack (even if it’s part of a full attack in which she hits that creature with another attack). The enemy must attack no one other than the subject, and the subject gains a +2 dodge bonus to AC against the triggering enemy’s attacks. Both of these effects last for 1 round. The bonus to AC increases by 1 for every 5 levels the mesmerist possesses. This is a mind-affecting compulsion effect.

Would this prevent an opponent to take attacks of opportunity against anyone but the subject of the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  You wrote it, "The enemy must attack no one other than the subject, and (...)"

Lasts for one round, so if triggered during the subject's turn, it'll last until the subject's next turn starts.  (You could theoretically activate it when the subject misses with an attack of opportunity, which would make it last until just before the triggering creature's next turn.  Might be less useful this way, since it won't catch the enemy's entire normal turn, but I can still see uses.  Maybe the enemy charged past the subject, the subject took their AoO and missed, pop goes the trick, now the charging creature can't make the attack at the end of their charge.)